# How to extract particular digits from numbers?

Tags: c++

I have `BYTE bMins = 36;` and I want `bMin1 = 3;` and `bMin2 = 6;`

Is it possible without long switches, etc.?

I've already tried it with `case`, but that's very slow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Integer division and modulo help:

```
BYTE bMins = 36;
BYTE bMin1 = bMins / 10;
BYTE bMin2 = bMins % 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() 
{
    typedef unsigned char BYTE;
    BYTE bMins = 36;
    BYTE bMin1, bMin2;

    auto d = std::div( bMins, 10 );
    bMin1 = d.quot;
    bMin2 = d.rem;

    std::cout << "bMin1 = " << ( int )bMin1 << ", bMin2 = " << ( int )bMin2 << std::endl; 
}
```

The program output is

```
bMin1 = 3, bMin2 = 6
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way is to convert to a string and use the digit characters:

```
BYTE bMins = 36;
std::string s = std::to_string(bMins);
BYTE bMin1 = s[0] - '0';
BYTE bMin2 = s[1] - '0';
```

Comment: @JiříNový _"I though that nobody will help me"_ Why actually? Do you think your question might not be well asked? So improve it please. Also there might be a number of duplicates found on the site answering exactly your problem.